# Require JS - r.js optimization - how to do this right?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, r.js

I am trying to optimize my Require JS project to a single file.
I walked over multiple tutorials but none of them seem to work properly.

I have the following files structure:

```
scripts/
    build/
        r.js
        build.js
    common/
        misc.js
        slider.js
    library/
        jquery.min.js
        jquery.colorbox.min.js
        jquery.scrollTo.min.js
        ...
    mobile/
        app.js
        catalogue.js
        car-images.js
        ...
    web/
        app.js
        catalogue.js
        car-images.js
        ...
index.html
```

I need to create 2 files `web.app.js` and `mobile.app.js`.
After multiple tries, I managed only to minify `app.js` in each folder but without it's dependencies.

The result should be one files, containing all the contents of `common`, `library` and `web` / `mobile` directories, depending on which app.js I try to compile.

Here is how `app.js` looks like (`web` and `mobile` are similar):

```
requirejs.config({
    "paths": {
        'jquery': [
            '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min',
            '../library/jquery.min'
        ],
        'colorbox': [
            '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.4.33/jquery.colorbox-min',
            '../library/jquery.colorbox-min'
        ],
        'colorbox-he': [
            '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.4.33/i18n/jquery.colorbox-he.min',
            '../library/jquery.colorbox-he.min'
        ],
        'scrollTo': [
            '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/2.1.1/jquery.scrollTo.min',
            '../library/jquery.scrollTo.min'
        ],
        'misc': '../common/misc',
        'slider': '../common/slider'
    },
    "map": {
        '*': {
            'colorbox': 'colorbox-he'
        },

        'colorbox-he': {
            'colorbox': 'colorbox'
        }
    },
    "shim": {
        'scrollTo': {
            'deps': ['jquery'],
            'exports': 'jQuery.fn.scrollTo'
        },
        'colorbox': {
            'deps': ['jquery'],
            'exports': 'jQuery.fn.colorbox'
        },
        'colorbox-he': ['colorbox'],
        'misc': ['jquery', 'scrollTo'],
        'car-images': ['jquery', 'colorbox'],
    }
});

if (typeof require_modules == 'object') {
    require_modules.push('misc')
} else {
    var require_modules = ['misc']
}

require(require_modules);
```

Here is the config used:

```
({
    baseUrl: "../web",
    name: "app",
    out: "app-built.js"
})
```

Any idea how to this right? because of the multiple files and requests, the loading time is pretty long.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question should include the configuration file you passed to `r.js`.

Comment: @Louis Yes you are right. I updated the answer. they were pretty simple so I thought maybe it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are asking `r.js` to process this:

```
if (typeof require_modules == 'object') {
    require_modules.push('misc')
} else {
    var require_modules = ['misc']
}

require(require_modules);
```

And it can't. The [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) is clear:

> The optimizer will only combine modules that are specified in arrays of string literals that are passed to top-level `require` and `define` calls, or the `require('name')` string literal calls in a simplified CommonJS wrapping. So, it will not find modules that are loaded via a variable name:
>
> ```
> var mods = someCondition ? ['a', 'b'] : ['c', 'd'];
> require(mods);
> ```
>
> but 'a' and 'b' will be included if specified like so:
>
> ```
> require(['a', 'b']);
> ```

Unfortunately, `r.js` just ignores calls to `require` that do not contain an array of string literal. You get no warning about it.

To solve this, you could have one `r.js` build configuration per bundle you want to create and hardcode the modules to be included. A more sophisticated solution would be to use something like [esprima](http://esprima.org/) to analyze your code and produce the build configurations for each bundle. Or you could write a script that is less capable than esprima but is able to extract the needed module names from files written according to a convention you decide. This is largely dependent on how your applications are structured.

Other issues with your configuration... You must use `mainConfigFile` in your build configuration or duplicate values from your runtime configuration (like `shim`) into your build configuration. I'd use `mainConfigFile`. If you ever use `require` calls that are not in the top level scope, you must also use `findNestedDependencies`. You probably also want `removeCombined`.

Comment: I have about 10 types of pages. each page loads different modules depending on it's needs. For example the page is using a slider, so a slider module will be added to `require_modules` to be loaded.

@Louis Because I know what modules are loaded on the PHP level, I should use something like that, and combine it later to an array like I did.

So how I can optimize it but still use dynamic inclusion?

Comment: The paragraph that beings with "To solve this..." goes over what you could do to get what you want. I can't be more specific because how to implement it is highly dependent on the specifics of your application.

Answer (score 0):

As Louis mentioned your main trouble is with your `if` statement.

While there are a lot of options for you, i'd approach this with 2 build scripts pointing at 2 config files (your app files), e.g to compile **web.app.js**:

**scripts/web/build.js**:

```
({
  mainConfigFile: 'app.js',
  optimize: 'uglify2',
  name: 'path/to/require.js', /* relative to where you run r.js */
  include: ['app'],
  insertRequire: ['app'],
  out: '../web.app.js',
  wrap: true
})
```

Install **r.js** globally then run the following from **scripts/web/**:

```
r.js -o build.js
```

Note: The above will only compile **require**, **misc** and it's dependencies **scrollTo** & **jQuery**